# How to comment out image address in markdown file in GitHub

Tags: github, markdown

I would like to comment out an image in a markdown file in GitHub, ie., show only the code but not the image itself, I tried this:`<!---   --->` but it leaves an empty space instead of showing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd want to display the syntax/code, wrap it in backticks.

## `` ` ``

In-line code requires one backtick at each end. `like me`.

The line above was:

```markdown
In-line code requires one backtick at each end. `like me`.
```

And if you want a complete code block with syntax highlighting, use three:  ```` ``` ```` . It will display like the code blocks in my answer.

So, something like this:

```markdown
![StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg)
```

Will display the StackOverflow logo when outside of backticks:

[image: StackOverflow]

Alternatively, if you comment it out

```markdown
<!---
![StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg)
--->
```

Your text will begin after a new line since the comment is practically whitespace now.